# How to resolve the error: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller

I am building a spring mvc web application with Hibernate ORM.

I first tried a Hello world application then i added some code to integrate Hibernate and JPA. When i run the application i get the following error: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Here is my servlet

```java
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"></context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.test"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

and here is web.xml

```java
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application </display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and here is pom.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>springTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>springMVC</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>springMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>jstl</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version> 2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>




      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.json</groupId>
          <artifactId>json</artifactId>
          <version>20180813</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>springMVC</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

and here is the conroller

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {

        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{userId}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {

        userRepository.delete(userRepository.getOne(userId));

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

how can i fix this error?

Edit:

```java
javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet [HelloWeb] a généré une exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
cause mère

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Edit 2:output of command mvn dependency:tree

```java
[INFO] springTest:springMVC:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.json:json:jar:20180813:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

edit 3: peristence.xml under the directory WEB-INF

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpatestdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace (as that tells us which class cannot be found).

Comment: thank you for your response, see my edit  i added the stacktrace

Comment: can you share the output of command mvn dependency:tree

Comment: Spring Data JPA is build for Spring 5.1 NOT Spring 4.3. EIther upgrade the spring version you are using (to prevent jars from conflicting versions) or downgrade Spring Data JPA to the 1.11.x version to be 4.3 compatible.

Comment: thank you for you all, the solution is as proposed by M.Deinum, i now get a new error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType

Comment: This is again because of incompatible versions. You are including Hibernate 5.4 (JPA 2.2 and overriding the JPA api to the JPA 2.0 dependency. Just remove that dependency, HIbernate will take care of the correct JPA api version.

Comment: i did as you suggested, i get the following error : nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3db1a10a' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; ... Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]:  nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit

Comment: i added the persistence.xml , you can see my edit, the file is under WEB-INF directory

Comment: Consider to use Spring Boot, it much more easier to configure.
Either forget the xml config and use Java one.
It needs lot of experience to wire up spring yourself as well as you must understand the relations between components' versions. Spring Boot will bring the proper versions to your project, and it just fine for most of the projects.

Comment: I wish but i have to use Spring

Comment: i solved this error by puting persistence.xml in the path target/classes/META-INF